# How are augmented maximums calculated in SR5?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

I have probably simply overlooked it in the book, but three separate searches through the book have still failed to find it, so I thought I'd ask.  Sorry if it's obvious and I'm just missing it.

Several spells and power reference a character's "augmented maximum" for an Attribute.  I fail to find the calculation for this statistic.  I'm assuming it's something fairly obvious, probably Attribute*1.5 or Attribute*2, but I'd like to know for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Page 94, the last paragraph before "Cyberware & Bioware" heading, says the maximum augmentation to any single attribute is +4.  That's the TOTAL augmentation, so if you're getting a bonus from cyberware, the max your mage friend can buff you is reduced.  Likewise if you're a Burnout Adept trying to self-boost the same stat with both PP and 'ware.

A friend saw my question and messaged me the answer.  I figured I should put it up here in case others are in the boat with me.

Comment: Another consideration is that not all attribute boosts stack with each other. For example, having an Adept with Improved Reflexes 3 and Improved Physical Attribute (Reaction) will not bring you up to the maximum of +4 because Improved Reflexes explicitly states that it does not combine with anything else that improves Reaction or Initiative. Many groups choose to house-rule that you may buy a 4th rank of Improved Reflexes for an additional powerpoint in order to allow characters to hit the augmented maximum.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for pointing that out.  I think that might have been a bit of a balance thing because Adepts (and MAs, mein Gott) are so good.  A few initiations in and they're blinding fast anyway (as fast or faster as a 'decker or technomancer moving at the speed of information), with plenty of other powers to use and abuse.  Restricting them from that last d6 of initiative doesn't seem like a huge drawback.

Comment: @Dyndrilliac I believe that rule as written applies specifically to the initiative portion "the increase cannot be combined with other technological or magical increases to Initiative"